# Python scipy.stats - Get number for a specific probability at invweibull curve

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I'm developing a system in Python that returns a specific number given a needed probability in a statistic curve

My dataset contains each value of this variable that I call "data".
First I get this values and show the histogram of it

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from fitter import Fitter

data = pd.read_csv("124_2.csv", encoding='ISO-8859-1',sep=';',decimal=',') 

plt.hist(data)
plt.show()
```

[pareto distribution of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjXNa.png)

After the histogram I fit it to the best curve

```
dist_names = ['rayleigh', 
             'pareto',
             'exponnorm',
             'alpha',
             'loggamma',
             'lognorm',
             'laplace',
             'beta',
             'expon',
             'gamma',
             'lognorm',
             'norm',
             'pearson3',
             'triang',
             'uniform',
             'weibull_min',
             'weibull_max',
             'invweibull']

f = Fitter(data)
f.fit()
f.summary()
f.get_best(method='sumsquare_error')
```

[Data fitted to the best curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs6W3.png)

parameters from get_best = {'invweibull': (2.2940157, -3.159848, 17.021271)}

Now I get all parameters about the specific curve (in this case invweibull)
What I need now is to give a probability number (example 95%) and the system retrieve me the number that it represents. In this exemple, the 50.35

[The number of 95% probability is 50.35](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmlcQ.png)

How can I get this number given a probability?

Comment: Have you looked at the `fitter.get_best()` method?  Apparently it returns the parameters of the best fitted distribution.  See [documentation](https://fitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references.html#fitter.fitter.Fitter.get_best)

Comment: Hi Bill. I got the parameters using the get_best but I want to khow how to use them to get the spefic number. With these parameters I could just redraw the curve.
How do I use them to get the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `dist.ppf(0.95, *fit_result)`.